# when using QCustomPlot in qt the graph is drawn only when window is resized,why?

Tags: qt, qcustomplot

when the code to draw graph is placed in constructor the graph the graph is drawn fine , but while using the same code in slot of pushButton to draw graph the graph is only drawn when window size is changed

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
  {
ui->setupUi(this);
  }

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
 {
delete ui;
}

 void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
int month[12]={6 ,9 ,6, 5, 6, 4, 6 ,10, 6, 8, 5 ,5};
QBrush gray(Qt::gray);
ui->customPlot->setBackground(gray);
// create empty bar chart objects:
  QCPBars *bar = new QCPBars(ui->customPlot->xAxis, ui->customPlot->yAxis);
bar->setName("barerative");
bar->setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 168, 140).lighter(130)));
bar->setBrush(QColor(0, 168, 140));

// prepare x axis with country labels:
QVector<double> ticks;
QVector<QString> labels;
ticks << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5 << 6 << 7<<8<<9<<10<<11<<12;
labels << "January" << "February" << "March" << "April" << "May" << "June"             << "July"<<"August"<<"September"<<"October"<<"November"<<"December";
QSharedPointer<QCPAxisTickerText> textTicker(new QCPAxisTickerText);
textTicker->addTicks(ticks, labels);
ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTicker(textTicker);
ui->customPlot->xAxis->setRange(0, 8);
ui->customPlot->xAxis->grid()->setVisible(true);
ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTickLabelColor(Qt::black);
ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTickLabelFont(QFont("Times",14,2));

// prepare y axis:
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setRange(0, 15);

ui->customPlot->yAxis->setLabel("Total Sale");
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setBasePen(QPen(Qt::white));
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setTickPen(QPen(Qt::white));
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setSubTickPen(QPen(Qt::white));
ui->customPlot->yAxis->grid()->setSubGridVisible(true);
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setTickLabelColor(Qt::white);
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setLabelColor(Qt::white);
ui->customPlot->yAxis->grid()->setPen(QPen(QColor(130, 130, 130), 0, Qt::SolidLine));
ui->customPlot->yAxis->grid()->setSubGridPen(QPen(QColor(130, 130, 130), 0, Qt::DotLine));

// Add data:
QVector<double> Data;
Data<<month[0]<<month[1]<<month[2]<<month[3]<<month[4]<<month[5]<<month[6]<<month[7]<<month[8]<<month[9]<<month[10]<<month[11];
bar->setData(ticks, Data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call repaint on your QCustomGraph at the end of the function. Not sure what the exact call is.

The reason why it works when the window resizes is that when the resize is finished it repaints the view.